# PyQt on hover set style to another widget

Tags: python, pyqt, stylesheet, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I'm making an app with PyQt. I have my `QListWidget` with items. I set widget to them as I want two lines of text to be shown with `setItemWidget`. The widget includes two labels, for text and date.

How can I set **StyleSheet** to both of my labels in my widget when I hover the item?
I could set it to the label itself but i need to change both of them.
Can i affect another widget when hovering a different one?

Thank you.